# is it possible to capture the traffic of websocket using wireshark

Tags: wireshark

I have a websocket connection to wss://ws.example.com, is it possible to capture the websocket traffic using wireshark? I have already tried to using `websocket` filter in wireshark `Version 4.2.0 (v4.2.0-0-g54eedfc63953)` followed this doc https://wiki.wireshark.org/WebSocket.  but filter nothing. I can see the websocket traffic from google chrome network devtools.

Comment: `wss://` means its transport encrypted. Wireshark will only see the encrypted TLS traffic.

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to capture the traffic of websocket using wireshark

yes. Since it's also running over your network interface, it gets captured.